# python import techniques for multiple files using same libraries

Tags: php, python, file-io, import, include

Okay I have a question, I'm wondering what is the equivalent to `including` many files into a `single php file` (say this file is called `init.php`). And for instance `init.php` reads over `Directory X` and includes every file `*.php`. Any files included within these files imported by `init.php` would now be shared across the script (or system).

In similar example but this time with `python`, I have a file called `init.py` that reads over `Directory Y` and `imports` each module (or package) using [find_packages()](http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html#using-find-packages) would lines such as `import numpy as np, os, sys` be included across the files within `Directory Y` or would each of these files require this `import` line? inorder to access the `os` and `sys`? would the python example have the same or different implications from the php example? and why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you `import` a file then Python will perform two different steps:

1. Open the imported module file and execute it, including any `import` statements in the module.
2. Make the imported module available in the namespace of the current module.

Note that if you import module `foo` then you won't have access to the modules imported by `foo` in your namespace - you'd need to import them directly (or access them via `foo.module`, but generally you'd want to import them in your module).

In short, every file that wants to use module `foo` needs to import it, even if other files in the same application use it as well.

One thing that might be confusing if you're coming from another language is that Python only ever actually executes a given module once (unless you call `reload()`), even if it's imported in many places. This is why I split the action of `import` up into two halves above - the first one is only executed once for each imported module, but the second one always happens.

So, if you do `import foo` which itself executes `import bar` then both `foo` and `bar` have been loaded and executed once. Your module has access to `foo`, but not `bar` since you haven't imported it (again, you could use it as `foo.bar`, but that's not very good practice typically). If you now run `import bar` then you will have `bar` available in your module, but since that module has already been imported once Python will *not* load and execute the module a second time.

The specifics of how modules work is well documented in the [official Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) if you need more details.

Does that answer your question?

**Extra details**

Often you don't need to load modules at runtime by scanning directories, but there are cases where that can be useful (e.g. implementing plugins). If you just want to choose between a fixed list of modules based on which are installed, you can just do a standard `import` and catch the `ImportError` and handle it by trying the next in the list.

If you *do* need to load modules when you don't know the names until runtime, you can use [importlib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html). The Python standard library also provides [several other modules for importing modules](http://docs.python.org/2/library/modules.html), such as [imp](http://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html) which has functions for locating and importing modules by filename.

It sounds like you've already got a solution for that, but it's sometimes useful to know what else is available (and these modules are all part of the standard library, so always installed).

Comment: yeah it does! thank you :), will select once timer has expired. Thanks again!